# writing a program using switch error

Tags: java, switch-statement

Kindly check why my "stringYear" appears to have not been initialized? Everytime I build the file in jcreator, 1 error appears and it says - variable yearString may not have been initialized.

instruction was to get input (year code 1 - 4) and output it as 1 for First year and Freshmen, 2 for Second Year and Sophomore, 3 for 3rd year and Junior, and 4 for 4th year and Senior.

Code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

public class yearSWITCH {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter year code: ");  
    System.out.println("");

        int year = 4;
        String yearString;
        switch (year) {
            case 1: yearString = "First Year";
                    yearString = "Freshmen";
                    break;
            case 2: yearString = "Second Year";
                    yearString = "Sophomore";
                    break;
            case 3: yearString = "Third Year";
                    yearString = "Junior";
                    break;
            case 4: yearString = "Fourth Year";
                    yearString = "Senior";
                    break;
        }
        System.out.println(yearString);
    }
}
```

Comment: `year` is not a constant variable. The compiler doesn't validate its value. As such, it could be any `int` value, the `switch` may not find a corresponding `case` and `yearString` may not be initialized.

Comment: What if `year` is `5`? What should be printed in `System.out.println(yearString);`?

Comment: Also what value of `yearString` you expect after case `1`? What do you think happens in `yearString = "First Year"; yearString = "Freshmen";`?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know, we have not discussed it in class. :(

Comment: The output should be either of the 4 depends on the user input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must initialize your `String` with any value, for your case, it would work fine if you initialize your `String` as below:

```
String yearString = ""; //String is empty
```

But consider in mind that your *second statement* in `any case (1,2,3,4)` will **override** any previous values of the variable `yearString` and therefore, the only output in the `print` statement for the `particular case` would be *Senior*. Solution for this problem would be initializing `2 Strings` and do the changes as below:

```
String yearString1 = "";
String yearString2 = "";
    switch (year) {
        case 1: yearString1 = "First Year";
                yearString2 = "Freshmen";
                break;
        case 2: yearString1 = "Second Year";
                yearString2 = "Sophomore";
                break;
        case 3: yearString1 = "Third Year";
                yearString2 = "Junior";
                break;
        case 4: yearString1 = "Fourth Year";
                yearString2 = "Senior";
                break;
        default:
                System.out.println("Invalid Input");
                break;
    }
    System.out.println(yearString1 + "\n " +yearString2);
```

Comment: I did use what you said and the output is only Senior, also, it complies but I am not able to enter any number. it automatically displayed "enter year code" and Senior. what could be the problem?

Comment: @FinnDonovan That is because you are not scanning the value of `year` instead, you are assigning it's value to `4`. Remove the line `int year = 4;` and replace it with `int year = keyboard.nextInt();`

Comment: done. it is now working but my problem now is on how to output it something like this -     First Year    Freshman in different lines. Also, how can I end it when the user entered numbers other than 1 to 4?

Comment: @FinnDonovan Edited my answer to resolve both of your queries. Use `"\n"` for a _newline_ and `default:` for any other inputs except the required ones. Please do accept my answer if it solves your entire problem :))

Comment: Yes, yes... everything is now how I wanted it to be.. Thank you so much sir!!! I have accepted and checked it just like what I do everytime I get an excellent help. Thanks!

Comment: @FinnDonovan Anytime :)) Btw I'm not a Sir, just a 2nd Year(3rd Sem) Info & Comm Tech college Student ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize it.

```
String yearString = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below code .. I think this will  clear your doubt. while writing the code , please use IDE . IDE will help you to find the errors.

Code is :

```
package com.raju;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class YearCheck {

    public static void main(String[] a) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter year code: ");  

        int year = keyboard.nextInt();
        String yearString="";
        switch (year) {
            case 1: yearString = "First Year";
                    yearString = "Freshmen";
                    break;
            case 2: yearString = "Second Year";
                    yearString = "Sophomore";
                    break;
            case 3: yearString = "Third Year";
                    yearString = "Junior";
                    break;
            case 4: yearString = "Fourth Year";
                    yearString = "Senior";
                    break;
            default:
                System.out.println("you have entered the value greater than 4");
                break;
        }
        System.out.println(yearString);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have already accepted Mr. Robot because he gave me the the right codes earlier. I would want to check yours for your effort but it will invalidate his.. so what I can do is to upvote yours..thanks you for trying to help...